# Instance object does not work properly with animator in Unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making games using Unity and I have some problems and I will ask questions.
The animator of an object instantiated using a prefab does not work properly, and precisely a specific event is a problem. The object placed in the hierarchy is fine. However, certain events do not work for objects instantiated using a script.

this is code.

```
  public Animator guestmove;
    public void Jump_motion()
    {
        if (tag == "Boy")
        {
            guestmove.SetTrigger("Jump");
        }
    }
    public void Angry_motion()
    {
        guestmove.SetTrigger("Angry");

    }
```

Here, we implement the event by pressing a button.
I changed the code to work when the tags match, but the objects I placed in the hierarchy also do not work.

This is the code that creates the instance.

```
    if (currentlyObject > 0){                            
   boyObject = Instantiate(boy, tableObject.transform.position, tableObject.transform.rotation);  
   boyObject.transform.Translate(new Vector3(0, -3, -11));

   girlObject = Instantiate(girl, tableObject.transform.position, tableObject.transform.rotation);
   girlObject.transform.Translate(new Vector3(1.5f, -3, -11));
                        }
```

I kept searching for the relevant data, but I could not find any cases of similar problems. I do not know where the problem is, please help me.

this is link

(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SKbSIfFQM4-n8l-ZBBvZb_3SuNx-kd5-/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Where is the code that triggers these functions?

Comment: Where the issue lies, is hard to say. Is it possible for you to provide a screenshot or so of your animation with the variables being manipulated over time? The issue could be because of local vs global changes.

Answer (score 0):

Use the transition to triggers from Any State, this should work.

And where are your functions called?